# Como fazer corretamente essa condição?

Tags: php, mysql, require

Eu fiz essa condição, para que se a pessoa pesquisar pelo nome andrey ira executar um require, caso contrário não ira exibir, portanto qualquer nome que ponho no campo de busca esta trazendo o require, assim está o meu código:

```
if ($resultados->num_rows > 0) {
    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
        echo utf8_encode("<strong>Nome: </strong>" . $linha['nome'] . "</br>");
        print ("<strong>Endereço: </strong>" . $linha['endereco']."</br>");
        if( isset($_POST['cidade']) && $_POST['cidade'] === 'sao-gabriel-da-palha' ) {
            $fromPerson = 'São Gabriel da Palha';
            echo "<strong>Cidade: </strong>".$fromPerson."</br>";
        }
        print ("<strong>Telefone: </strong>" . $linha['telefone']."</br>");
        echo "<strong>email: </strong>". $linha['email']."</br>";
        if (isset($_POST['nome']) === 'Andrêy Ferraz' || 'Andrêy' || 'Ferraz' || 'Andrey'){
           require 'andreyferraz.php';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Nenhum resultado para a sua busca.";
}

$conexao->close();
```

---

@rray deu isso aqui no resultado da busca
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja que no código você compara `$_POST['nome']` isso parace não existir o correto seria `$_POST['palavra']` nos if. Precisa esclarecer isso.

Comment: coloquei 'palavra' e continua não trazendo o require... minha nossa to ficando louco com isso já

Comment: Editei a resposta com a correção.

Comment: Cara não entendo, o require so funciona se eu coloco no else, mais dai qualquer coisa que busco acaba o exibindo

Comment: Antes você estava comparando os valores errados não existia nenhum campo chamado `nome` no seu form (html) aí `$_POST['nome'] == 'algo'` sempre vai retornar `false`. Precisa definir o que deseja comparar.

Comment: sim, mais troquei por palavra e não resolveu nada

Comment: Deve ter problema em outra parte do código, pois a comparação é aquilo que está na resposta. Precisa fazer um debug minucioso agora, imprimir o valor das variáveis verificar  onde o código passa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tratamento da String

Uma outra coisa importante é fazer o tratamento dessa string, nunca podemos confiar no que o usuário vai digitar, e fazer essa condição sem acentuação com tudo minúsculo aumentará a taxa de êxito na busca.

```
if (isset($_POST['palavra'])) {
  $palavra = preg_replace("/&([a-z])[a-z]+;/i", "$1", htmlentities(strtolower(trim($_POST['palavra'])))); 
}
```

Depois disso você usa a variável `$palavra` para fazer a condição ao invés do `$_POST['palavra']`.

Aplicando nos dois exemplos da primeira resposta do [rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91/rray):

```
if (isset($palavra) &&
   ($palavra === 'andrey ferraz' ||
    $palavra === 'andrey' ||
    $palavra === 'ferraz')){
```

.

```
if (!empty($palavra) && 
    in_array($palavra, array('andrey ferraz', 'andrey', 'ferraz'))){
```

Entendendo o que cada função faz:

- **preg_replace();** faz a substituição dos caracteres acentuados
- **strtolower();** converte todos os caracteres da string em minúsculo
- **trim();** exclui todos os espaços em branco no começo e no fim da string

Comment: amigo, obrigado, deu certo do jeito que vc mostrou ai

Comment: Mais tem um problema @Filipe Ricardo, se eu colocar por exemplo pra buscar 'Andrêy' retorna tudo em branco... como resolver isso?

Comment: A forma como eu passei é para fazer a condição, essa consulta você está fazendo pelo banco de dados? Sugiro que poste o código dessa parte. Com o código que te passei, o Andrêy fica andrey, segue o link com o exemplo rodando https://repl.it/MMxC/6

Comment: veja aqui o código:      if (isset($_POST['palavra'])) { // remover acentos
            $palavra = preg_replace("/&([a-z])[a-z]+;/i", "$1", htmlentities(strtolower(trim($_POST['palavra']))));
        }
        if (!empty($palavra) &&
            in_array($palavra, array('andrey ferraz', 'andrey', 'ferraz', 'Andrêy', 'Andrêy Ferraz', 'Andrêy Martins Ferraz'))){
            require 'andreyferraz.php';
        }
E sim, é pelo banco de dados mysql

Comment: Como você converteu tudo o que o usuário digitou deixando sem acento e em minúsculo, na condição você precisa colocar tudo sem acento e em minúsculo também. Segue o exemplo funcionando https://repl.it/MMxC/7

Comment: ta mais e fiz isso ai, e quando coloco no campo de busca a palavra "Andrêy" não me retorna nada, mas se eu coloco "Andrey" ai retorna

Comment: faz assim, coloque um print_r($_POST['palavra']); numa linha acima da sua condição, repita a busca digitando "Andrêy" e cola aqui o resultado desse print

Comment: eu fiz e não retornou nada!

Comment: Se o print não retornou nada então o problema está no $resultados, a sua consulta sql não retornou nenhum resultado. Poste o seu código na parte em que é feita essa consulta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66896/discussion-between-filipe-ricardo-and-wpfan).

Answer (score 8):

```
if (isset($_POST['palavra']) === 'Andrêy Ferraz' || 'Andrêy' || 'Ferraz' || 'Andrey'){
```

Não funciona como esperado. A comparação feita é se existe algo na string compara com `true`. É comum em linguagens de programação você repetir o predicado para varias comparações, poderia reescrever da seguinte forma:

```
if (isset($_POST['palavra']) &&
   ($_POST['palavra'] === 'Andrêy Ferraz' ||
    $_POST['palavra'] === 'Andrêy' ||
    $_POST['palavra'] === 'Ferraz' ||
    $_POST['palavra'] === 'Andrey')){
```

Nesse caso a melhor opção para comparar varios valores é a função `in_array()`.

```
if (!empty($_POST['palavra']) && 
    in_array($_POST['palavra'], array('Andrêy Ferraz', 'Andrêy', 'Ferraz', 'Andrey'))){
```

Se achar mais legível pode pegar o resultado das funções e atribuir em variáveis e comparar no if.

```
$temNome = !empty($_POST['palavra']) ? $_POST['palavra'] : false;
$nomeEncontrado = in_array($temNome, array('Andrêy Ferraz', 'Andrêy', 'Ferraz', 'Andrey'));

if($temNome && $nomeEncontrado){
   require 'arquivo.php';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Agora o código está assim, e dessa vez o require não esta sendo mais exibido de nenhuma forma, e ele deveria ser exibido quando pesquisasse pelo nome 'andrey':

```
if ($resultados->num_rows > 0) {
    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
        echo utf8_encode("<strong>Nome: </strong>" . $linha['nome'] . "</br>");
        print ("<strong>Endereço: </strong>" . $linha['endereco']."</br>");
        if( isset($_POST['cidade']) && $_POST['cidade'] === 'sao-gabriel-da-palha' ) {
            $fromPerson = 'São Gabriel da Palha';
            echo "<strong>Cidade: </strong>".$fromPerson."</br>";
        }
        print ("<strong>Telefone: </strong>" . $linha['telefone']."</br>");
        echo "<strong>email: </strong>". $linha['email']."</br>";
        if (!empty($_POST['nome']) &&
            in_array($_POST['nome'], array('Andrêy Ferraz', 'Andrêy', 'Ferraz', 'Andrey'))){

         print  require 'andreyferraz.php';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Nenhum resultado para a sua busca.";
}
```